# Help determining if an equation is a function of x

Tags: graphing-functions, absolute-value, ceiling-and-floor-functions

Graph:

1. ${y\over|y|}={x\over|x|}$
2. ${\lfloor x \rfloor \lfloor y \rfloor = 1}$

Determine if each graph represents a function of x and explain your answer.

I've never seen anything like the before and I'm not sure where to start.

Comment: Try distinguishing cases: positive $y$, negative $y$, postive $x$, negative $x$ to get rid of the absolute values, and do a similar thing for the floor function.

Comment: Don't tell me what to do.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**:

1. ${y\over|y|}={x\over|x|}$
   \begin{cases}
   x \ge 0 \Rightarrow \frac{x}{|x|} = \frac{y}{|y|} = 1 \Rightarrow y \ge 0 \\
   x \lt 0 \Rightarrow \frac{x}{|x|} = \frac{y}{|y|} = -1 \Rightarrow y \lt 0 \\
   \end{cases}
   So ${y\over|y|}={x\over|x|}$ is a general way to refer to every functions whose graph is in the $I$ and $III$ quadrant of a *Cartesian coordinate system*.
2. ${\lfloor x \rfloor \lfloor y \rfloor = 1} \Rightarrow \lfloor y \rfloor = \frac{1}{\lfloor x \rfloor} \ldots$